# generate buffer before `unload`

Tags: buffer, rxjs

I'm tracking events in a web page using `RxJs` and sending them through buffer.
I emit a buffer on `unload` event, but it's done after the event is triggered, so it's never triggered.
Is there a way to generate everything related to my buffer on `unload` ?

```
/* globals $ */

import { Observable } from 'rx-dom'
import { Load, Unload } from './events'

$(function () {
  const load$ = (new Load()).observer$() // triggered on page load
  const unload$ = (new Unload()).observer$() // triggered on page unload

  const source$ = Observable.merge(load$, unload$)

  const intervalBetween = 5000
  const dummyStart$ = Observable.return({})
  const bufferizeEvents$ = [submit$, unload$]
  const opening$ = dummyStart$
    .concat.apply(dummyStart$, bufferizeEvents$)
    .flatMapLatest(x => Observable.timer(0, intervalBetween))
    .skip(1)

  const buffers$ = source$.buffer(opening$)

  buffers$.subscribe(buffer => {
    if (buffer.length) {
      // some ajax call
      // this is never reached on page unload
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Such as it is formulated it is hard to make sense of your question? Could you do a marble diagram? And/or post the relevant code?

Comment: hi @user3743222 (good to see you :) i mean that using `buffer` from `Observable.fromEvent()` actually never goes to `buffer` function on `unload` event

Comment: good to see you too. Could you post the failing code?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jney/e8baebe76bc2f47efdd0d431b97dfd3b#file-index-js-L25

Comment: switch unload with another event that you can simulate and see if that event is properly processed.

Comment: yes i did. it works well. the point is on unload, i can see the event is proceed, but doesn't reach the buffer creation

Comment: then check that unload$ is actually emitting anything. Would be nice to publish your `unload()` code. If nothing wrong there, then try `const bufferizeEvents$ = Rx.Observable.merge(submit$, unload$)`

Comment: The `gist` has been updated